# Не происходит выборки с помощью функции strftime SQLite android

Tags: android, sqlite

Добрый день! Я хочу сделать выборку по дате в таблице. Но к сожалению выборка не происходит. Запрос в логах следующий:

```
SELECT * FROM 'TICKETS' WHERE strftime('%s', DATETIME) > strftime('%s', '07.08.2017 15:39')
```

У меня есть подозрение что дело в формате дата и время как в формате записанной, так и в формате дата и время, с которыми я сравниваю. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаяю не так?

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM 'TICKETS' WHERE strftime('%s', DATETIME) > strftime('%s', '" + result + "')";

Cursor cursor = dbHelper.getReadableDatabase().rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
```

Comment: в каком формате у вас DATETIME?

Comment: DATETIME в формате TEXT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если DATETIME у вас хранится в стандртном виде, а именно:

```
YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss
```

То ваш запрос должен выглядеть так:

```
String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM 'TICKETS' WHERE  DATETIME > Datetime('" + result  + "')";
```

**НО** у `result` должен быть такой же формат (как был описан выше). Например, `'2017-08-07 14:44:00'`

Comment: Всё ясно, значит мне нужно поменять форматы для даты как для строки result, так и для данных формата поля DATETIME. Они сейчас совпадают, но не вида YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss